# How to solve QuickSight SQL exception timeout error

Tags: amazon-athena, sqlexception, amazon-quicksight

I have created a VIEW in Amazon Athena using:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW sentiment_analysis AS 
SELECT 
    file, 
    Sentiment, 
    SentimentScore.Positive AS Positive, 
    SentimentScore.Negative AS Negative, 
    SentimentScore.Neutral AS Neutral, 
    SentimentScore.Mixed AS Mixed 
FROM "targeted_sentiment_output"."sentiment_results"
```

The VIEW works and populates with the data.

I am now trying to load this into Amazon QuickSight, but get the following error:

```
Your database generated a SQL exception. This can be caused by query timeouts, resource constraints, unexpected DDL alterations before or during a query, and other database errors. Check your database settings and your query, and try again.
```

I think it may be a timeout error. I have tried to find the Advanced Settings tab to increase the query timeout limit but can't find it. Please can you provide clear instructions on where to locate the timeout limit?

If it is a different error then please explain...

Thanks!